# Fast (effective & efficient) method to copy Java bean properties

Tags: java, performance, properties, javabeans

I have this bean that has up to 200 properties. I have to copy to another bean with a slightly different structure but with as many as 200 properties.

What is the most efficient and effective way to copy these properties. By default I am doing:

```
bean1.setProperty1(bean2.getProperty1Equivalent());
....
bean1.setProperty200(bean2.getProperty200Equivalent());
```

Some times, this takes 0 CPU time to complete, but when transaction increases it could take anything between 500milliseconds to 1000millseconds. I am hoping there is a smarter/faster way to copy these properties.

Is there a better way to do this, without having to modify both beans?

Comment: Are you looking for an utility class so you can get rid of the boilerplate or you want something which is faster than this?

Comment: The problem is the speed, so I want something faster in terms of CPU processing.

Comment: There won't be any faster way. If you really need another object with the same properties as the source object, then there is no other way than to copy them. In fact, this looks like a design flaw. And mybe this is an [XY issue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I agree with @Seelenvirtuose.

Comment: I think @Seelenvirtuose is right. I was hoping against hope. And I think the problem is called [False Dilemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_dilemma). That explains why ISO8583 messages are package as such and not XMLs/JSONs.

Comment: Copying a few hundreds field simply **can not take long**. If this is the most time-consuming part of the application, you're definitely doing something wrong.